# Windows taskkill is not working post Java upgrade

Tags: java, windows, process, upgrade

I upgrade Java to the latest version.
Now its Version 8 201. 
Post upgrade I was trying to kill a windows process that was not generated by Java.
I tried below command but neither java is throwing any exception nor killing the process

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /f /im XXX.exe");

Where XXX is my process image name

Can anyone please help me

Answer (score -1):

Now its working. Not sure what the problem